# Whats "integration time" in two photon microscopy?

Tags: photons, time, integration, microscopy

What is the meaning "integration time" in Two-photon excitation microscopy?
Why a mode-locked signal (laser) can reduce the "integration time" in Two-photon excitation microscopy?